# Finding function given ratio of derivatives w.r. to different variables

Tags: calculus, integration, numerical-methods, partial-derivative

Is there any way to find a function $f(a,b)$ up to some factors and a constant, given the ratio $$\frac{\partial f / \partial a}{\partial f/ \partial b}$$? If not, is there any other useful information about $f$ one can get from this ratio or a good numerical method to approximate $f$?
Thanks for helping me out.

Comment: EDIT: The idea is to find THE specific function $f$ in the situation where one only knows this ratio. Say the ratio is $\frac{2b}{a}$, how do i get $f(a,b) = a^2b$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose we know
$$
\frac{f_a}{f_b}=r(a,b).
$$
Then at a point $(a,b)$, the directional derivative of $f$ in the direction $[1,-r(a,b)]$ is $0$. This implies that $f$ is constant along the solution curves to the ODE
$$
\frac{db}{da}=-r(a,b).
$$

In your example
$$
\frac{f_a}{f_b}=\frac{2b}{a},
$$
the ODE we get is
$$
\frac{db}{da}=-\frac{2b}{a},
$$
which is separable. The solution curves are of the form $a^2b=C$, where $C$ is a constant. If $g$ is any function of one variable, then $g(a^2b)$ will be constant along the curves $a^2b=C$, so will give a solution to your original equation.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure this is what you were looking for but $f(a,b)=\lambda a+b$ has $$\frac{\frac{\partial f}{\partial a}}{\frac{\partial f}{\partial b}}=\frac \lambda 1=\lambda$$

Comment: The idea is to find THE specific function $f$
in the situation where one only knows this ratio. Say the ratio is $\frac{2b}{a}$, how do i get $f(a,b)=a^2b$?

Comment: So the ratio is not a constant? Can you separate it into some function of $a$ multiplied with a function of $b$?

Comment: Yes sorry, the ratio is a function of a and b itself. No, one has only the analytic expression, but it could contain something like $sin(ab)$ etc.

Comment: I'm not sure it's solvable in general case. Maybe some separation of variables is possible.